# Django field lookup returns case-insensitive result even with __exact

Tags: python, django

Here is my view:

```
@csrf_exempt
def api(request):
    if request.method=="POST" and 'cmd' in request.POST and request.POST['cmd'] == "post":
        try:
            usr = Usr.objects.get(secret__exact=request.POST['secret'])
            # ....
            response = 'ok'
        except Exception as ex:
            response = 'fail'

        return HttpResponse(response)
```

Django still returns the right object even with a wrong secret (for example if I replace an 'A' by an 'a' in the secret). What's wrong?

Comment: Are you saying the `response` is _always_ `OK` ?

Comment: if the secret in the DB is 'A1b2C', repsonse is OK even if the posted secret is 'a1b2C'. response is fail if I post a secret of 'b1b2C'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the collation of your database, specially if you are using MySQL. See the documentation here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-exact

It says:
In MySQL, a database table’s “collation” setting determines whether exact comparisons are case-sensitive. This is a database setting, not a Django setting.

Which means, it's the setting on your database that determines the case-sensitivity not what you write in python.